# making vars accessible across phases

Tags: racket

How can I make the same variable accessible across multiple phases? For instance:

`(define foo 1)
(define-for-syntax bar foo)`

would complain that `foo` is not defined in phase 0.

Comment: The short answer is you can't really (and shouldn't even if you could). There are some hacks however that you can use to get around this. I'm about to fall asleep, but if this isn't answered in the morning I'll be happy to show you some of them. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want this "variable" for. Here are some options:

1. You want it to be an immutable, primitive value.
2. You want it to be immutable, but complex data like a struct (not primitive).
3. You want it to be *mutable*.

In Leif Andersen's comment, where she said "you can't really, and shouldn't even if you could". I'm guessing she was talking about (3). The Racket compiler tries to make (3) impossible within the "internal" Racket runtime system. In the Racket documentation this is called the [*The Separate Compilation Guarantee*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._separate-compilation%29). There are good reasons behind [The Separate Compilation Guarantee](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._separate-compilation%29) and why (3) is a bad idea, and Leif Andersen or Matthew Flatt could explain those reasons much better than me. The paper [*Composable and Compilable Macros: You Want it When?*](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/macromod.pdf) and the talk [*Racket: Metaprogramming Time!*](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/racket-metaprogramming) explain some of those reasons.

However, in case an immutable value is enough, I will try to show answers for (1) and (2).

### 1: immutable, primitive data

Since the data is immutable, it's okay to have "two different identifiers" at different phases. If they start with the same value, and neither one is mutated, then they will stay at the same value.

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define foo 1))
(define foo 1)
```

However, this does not guarantee that the two `foo` variables have the same value, even if they look the same. It is possible for the "for-syntax" environment and the normal environment to be different, and interpret those expressions differently. To make sure that doesn't happen, it's better to have a *single* definition of `foo` in a module. This makes sure that it always has the same consistent environment. Then you can require that module multiple times, for both "for-syntax" and the normal way:

```
(module foo racket
  (provide foo)
  (define foo 1))

(require (for-syntax 'foo)
         'foo)
```

### 2: immutable, complex data

There are two ways to extend this to complex data like structs:

- using [*prefab*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structures.html#%28tech._prefab%29) structs
- using [*cross-phase-persistent*](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._cross-phase._persistent-modules%29) modules

#### 2a: immutable, complex data, prefab structs

Normally structs are "generative" meaning the a definition that looks the same written in two different places will generate two different struct types, and those structs will never be equal

However, structs with `#:prefab` are special because if you have the same definition in two different places, even at both "for-syntax" and normal levels, they do produce equal values.

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (struct rgb-color [r g b] #:prefab)
  (define red (rgb-color 255 0 0)))
(struct rgb-color [r g b] #:prefab)
(define red (rgb-color 255 0 0))
```

Or you can put this in a module as well, and require it at both the for-syntax and normal levels:

```
(module red racket
  (provide red)
  (struct rgb-color [r g b] #:prefab)
  (define red (rgb-color 255 0 0)))

(require (for-syntax 'red)
         'red)
```

#### 2b: immutable, complex data, cross-phase-persistent structs

If [prefab](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structures.html#%28tech._prefab%29) structs aren't good enough, and you want structs that feel less like "anything goes" primitive data, and more like an abstraction, there is a way to define a struct in a module that is specifically marked as [cross-phase-persistent](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._cross-phase._persistent-modules%29).

It's not a simple as writing `struct` however. The syntax of a [cross-phase-persistent](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._cross-phase._persistent-modules%29) is very restrictive. As far as I know, you would have to go low-level and use only `#%kernel` forms like `define-values` and [`make-struct-type`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingmorestructs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-struct-type%29%29). Your struct declarations might have to look like this:

```
#lang racket/kernel
(#%declare #:cross-phase-persistent)

(define-values [_1 rgb-color rgb-color? rgb-color-ref _5]
  (#%app make-struct-type 'rgb-color '#f '3 '0 '#f '() 'prefab '#f
         (#%app list '0 '1 '2)))
```

This is a much bigger hastle, so the more common solution is to just use [prefab](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structures.html#%28tech._prefab%29) structs instead.